# NameError: name 'Jan' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I keep getting this same error message ***NameError: name 'Jan' is not defined*** when i try run the code can someone tell me how to fix this

```
def main():
    # imports ability to read text files
    import csv
times=[1,273,93,59,266,128,2,41,110,315,43,263,3,78,649,620,538,502,4,456,648,618,537,501,5,238,156,160,310,127,6,768,647,616,534,459,7,6785,646,614,533,458,8,567,645,613,531,457,9,700,644,612,530,457,10,678,643,610,529,456,11,78,642,609,527,455,12,659,641,608,526,454,13,6543,640,606,525,453,14,567,639,605, 524,453,15,533,638,604,522,452,16,246,637,602,521,451,17,5,636,601,520,450,18,90,635,600,519,450,19,7,634,558,517,449]
    dates = [Jan,Feb,March,April,May]
     
    raceTimes = (input("PLease enter a time you would like to search for:"))
    found = False
    
    # open text file
    with open("sun_data.csv") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        
        # reads the text file
        for row in readCSV:
        # comparing values in text file with the user-entered time
              found = True
        for i in range(len(years)):
            if years[i] == x:
              found = True
            print(str(x) + " was found at position " + str(i))
            break
        if not found:
            print("I'm sorry, there is no race scheduled at that time.")
    # Close input file
    csvfile.close()
    
main()
```

Comment: `Jan` is a variable named Jan. `"Jan"` (quoted) is a string.

Comment: So does that mean I need to add quotation marks around Jan or in the brackets

Answer (score 4):

You probably meant to store the dates as strings?

if so change

```
dates = [Jan,Feb,March,April,May]
```

to

```
dates = ['Jan','Feb','March','April','May']
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the `NameError` because `Jan` is indeed not defined. I believe you wanted the months to be strings:

```
dates = ['Jan','Feb','March','April','May']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try to enter the items of the array 'dates'. It looks like the items should be strings which needs to set them in quotes.

dates = ["Jan","Feb","March","April","May"]

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp